# Highcharts load date values in X axis

Tags: json, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart which gets it's data from a JSON request.

```
function slowips(target){

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: target,
        type: 'spline',
        borderColor: '#0072C6',
        borderWidth: 3
    },
    title: {
            text: 'Responsetime'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Nr.1 is slowest'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Milliseconds'
        },
        min: 0


    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },  
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0,

    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {   
            animation: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            marker: {
            enabled: false
            }
        }

    },
    series: [{}]
};


 $.getJSON('graphs/test.php', function(data) {
    options.series = data; 
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}

slowips();
```

This is an example JSON input:

```
[ { "name":"sddf", "data": [ ["2013-02-01 00:01:00", 2 ], ["2013-02-02 00:02:00", 2.55 ]     ] } ]
```

Also tried:

```
[ { "name":"sddf", "data": [ [Date.UTC(12,  3, 09), 2 ], [Date.UTC(12,  3, 10), 2.55 ]   ] } ]
```

The first JSON example renders a chart, but with incorrect X axis data. The second JSON does not render the chart.

Please help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use timestamps, so when you load first JSON, then you need to parse it by Date.UTC() / Data.parse(), but functions cannot be places in json inside (as you have in second example).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that stamps had to be Unix timestamps in ms and without quotes.

Comment: It should be javascript timestamps, which are the same as unix but multiplied by 1000.